# I have this wire just exposed in my back yard. I am wondering what it is for?

Tags: wiring

This wire is coming down the back corner of my home from what I can gather. Now the breaker box is on the same side of house and very close to the location near the wire. Also the hvac unit is located a few feet above where the wire looks like it is coming from. Any help would be appreciated. Link to pictures below. Would not let me upload my pics due to being to large.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/FZduL8dTv1TBksys6

[image]

Comment: I put in a request that the site autoscale images. No useful response yet...

Comment: Difficult to tell from the pictures, but I would say it is underground feeder wire, potentially for an outdoor device that is neither buried or properly terminated. If so, you should have an electrician trace it and ensure it is not live before handling it.

Comment: get a close up picture of the cable.  is it plastic shealthed or bare copper wire?  if sheathed get a picture of any writing on the cables that identifies it.

Comment: Do you have a sprinkler system? What wires attach to the controller?

Answer (score 1):

In some parts of the photo one can see that the cable is thick at its edges and thinner in the middle, suggestive of having two insulated conductors at the edges and nothing (or a bare conductor) in the middle.

To my eye the cable looks like type UF-B, which is a kind of cable rated for indoor and outdoor mains-voltage electrical use. It might have been intended to power an outdoor outlet, yard light, or other appliance.

If indeed the cable is plastic-jacketed it may still have legible markings imprinted that would identify exactly what kind of cable it is.

It would be reasonable and prudent to try to track it, meaning to dig (carefully) where it enters the ground and follow where it leads. Alternatively, you could make informed guesses and check for a similar cable appearing in the circuit breaker panel or a nearby electrical outlet/junction box. If you did find a similar-looking cable end, it would be possible to determine whether that is the far end of this cable in the yard.